# Clear terminal using keyboard shortcut

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I was curious if there is a way to clear the terminal buffer/output through some keyboard shortcut. I am using Ubuntu. I am aware that

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

clears the terminal, but you can still scroll back to see the old text. I am looking for something similar to what

```
reset
```

command does. On Mac

<kbd>apple</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

seems to do the trick.

Comment: You can type "clear".

Comment: Thanks for mac command :D, i was looking for it

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In gnome terminal, you can edit the keyboard shortcuts with `Edit -> Reset Shortcuts...`  You can then map the command "Reset and Clear", which seems to do what you're looking for.

Alternatively, you can limit the scrollback history to a small number (say 0) and Ctrl+L will be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: This may have changed in newer versions of gnome and the gnome terminal. For me it's `Edit -> Preferences -> Shortcuts` (I'm using GNOME Terminal v3.16.2)

Comment: "Reset and Clear" was what I was looking for, except that it failed to preserve the prompt. Following immediately with Ctrl+L restores the prompt. So with Reset and Clear bound to Ctrl+K, I can hit Ctrl+K, Ctrl+L to clear the scrollback and leave me with a ready prompt.

Comment: Unfortunately while you can bind `Reset and Clear` to Ctrl+K, I can't find a way to unbind "clear to the beginning of the line", so now Ctrl+K deletes the shell prompt too. Hmmm.

Comment: Actually scratch that, the `Reset and Clear` action itself destroys the prompt, so this isn't really the same as Cmd+K on Mac.

Answer (score 39):

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> clears from cursor to beginning of line
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> clears from cursor to end of line
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> clears one character to the right of the cursor
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> clears one word to the left of the cursor
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> clears one word to the right of the cursor
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left/right</kbd> jumps to the beginning of the previous/next word
- <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> jumps to start of line
- <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> jumps to end of line

To clear the entire screen add the following alias to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias cls="echo -ne '\033c'"
```

Now, in a *new* terminal typing `cls` will clear everything including the scroll buffer. It works much faster than `reset` since it does not reset anything.

In fact `reset` is only needed when you want to fix a broken terminal, e.g. after running `cat` on a binary file.

If you are on OSX, then Command (<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>k</kbd> will clear the terminal <sub>(*also works in the chrome devtools console*)</sub>.

Comment: And how would I add a shortcut to do this using without typing out `cls`?

Comment: @FloatingRock: this would depend on your desktop environment and possibly your terminal, if the terminal has no way of attaching a command to a shortcut, then your only chance is to set a system-global shortcut which is DE-dependent. For example, in XFCE, that would be Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts, don't remember for other shells.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for months..

Comment: The program underneath most of these shortcuts is [readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Interaction.html). A standard in a lot of Repl environments.

Answer (score 10):

In Ubuntu 18.4 `Ctrl`+`Alt`+ `L` will do the trick.

Comment: VLQ reviewers: I think here a short answer is pretty okay.

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl+L redraws the terminal; it doesn't clear it.  If you're in a full-screen app like less or vim, the Ctrl-L command is what you use to redraw a corrupted screen.  In vim with color syntax highlighting, for example, you can use ctrl_l to update the colors if you scroll a long distance and vim gets confused by matching quotes or brackets or similar.

Just for reference if someone searches and finds this...  If you need to clear the scroll-back buffer, either set your buffer to 0 lines or close the window and reopen it.  Or "while true; do print; done" and then interrupt with ctrl+c when you've output enough lines to blow the buffer.  The scroll buffer is application dependent, so while the given solution works for Gnome terminal, it won't work for really any other terminal device.

Comment: This "blow the buffer" wont work for unlimited scrollback mode.

Answer (score 2):

I use Konsole.  I've always used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> in the past to clear everything, including the scrollback.  There is a new and better way now:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and Googling "konsole keyboard shortcuts clear history" doesn't get you there very easily, but it gets you here.

Answer (score 2):

on Ubuntu 20.04 in terminal, when you want to achieve the same as by clicking in menu on Advanced > 'Reset and Clear':

via shortcut, you can use: Ctrl+Shift+L

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.

Comment: Which terminal emulator does this work in?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu, open your terminal and go to Preferences - Shortcuts. There, find "Reset and Clear" option. Click that and type your shortcut as what you want. This works on my Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Trevor Dixon's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/299903/clear-terminal-using-keyboard-shortcut#comment1777209_299904) on the accepted answer, it's possible to (easily) make a shortcut that maps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to what you want.

1. Install [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Installing#package-manager-installation)
2. Open AutoKey and create a new script.
3. In the script, add `gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal` to the Window Filter.
4. In the script, set the Hotkey to `<ctrl>+k`.
5. In the script body, add the following:

   ```
   keyboard.send_keys('<ctrl>+<shift>+k')
   keyboard.send_keys('<ctrl>+l')
   ```
6. Save the script.
7. In the Terminal app, map Preferences > Shortcuts > Reset and Clear to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> in the Terminal app should clear all scrollback *and* show the prompt. In my experience this exactly matches what <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> does in macOS.